# CRM2011/JScript: SetStateRequest (changing statuscode) - other fields' changes didn't save

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm-2011, jscript

I have a form which statuscode has to be changed when a button is used. Altogether with the status some other fields has to be changed (from empty), filling with information that form has been accepted and with current date.

The button action code is as below:

```
if (comment != null){
 SetValue ("senddate",new Date());
 SetValue ("decision",100000000); //option set
 Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
 SDK.REST.SetStateRequest("entityname", Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId(), 0, NextStatus, ribbonButtonSuccsessCallback, genericErrorCallback);
}
```

The problem is that after using the button I can see, that "senddate" and "decision" are filled, but right after performing SDK.REST.SetStateRequest part they go back to blank/null. I must have the changes on the fields saved and visible.

I also tried using SetValue on "statuscode", but it didn't work well.

Comment: Are you switching from an *active* state to an *inactive* state or are you merely changing the statuscode (Status Reason) while keeping the statecode (Status)? In any case you cannot combine attribute changes with an SetStateRequest; you will have to save changes in a separate step.

Comment: Within this statuschange I remain in active state. I tried putting SDK.REST.SetStateRequest in other function (but within the same "if" condition) that was executed after saving the for, but it didn't help. I don't know how to trigger completely other function with the same and one button click. //Thanks for your prompt answer!

Comment: Crm2011 lacks the comfort of [Xrm.Page.data.save().then()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481607%28v=crm.6%29.aspx#BKMK_dataSave) introduced in Crm2013 - if you want to do this synchronously you might need a server-side plugin or handle it in the onLoad.

Comment: What problems did you experience with using setting the value on `statecode`? I'd expect this to work without issues as long as you keep the `state` active.

Comment: Firstly I used setting value on `statecode` and with this my other 2 fields are filled with data corectly. But I decided to go for `SetStateRequest` because I wanted the user to fill some comment field (`if (comment != null)`) . Before launching the function written in the question above, I put `(...)entity.save();` so the system will notify the user, if the required field is not filled. I assumed, that users after filling the field will go straight into clicking the acceptance button (without proper saving). `SetStateRequest` somehow let me save the form, what I couldn't do with `SetValue`.

Comment: I tried different ways to save the form before using `SetValue` on `statecode`. But `Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();` doesn't save the changes on the comment field (multilines text). Even when used before `SetValue` or even before the `if` function. Saving after changing the `statecode` doesn't do the job either.

Comment: Could it be that the `SetValue` method doesn't behave as expected? I'd try to use `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("senddate").setValue(new Date())` etc. to assign the field values. I cannot find any references if `Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()` is supported in Crm2011 which could solve your multiple `.save` just to validate the Form.

Comment: `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("senddate").setValue(new Date())` didn't resolve the problem while using `SDK.REST.SetStateRequest`.
Perhaps is it possible to put on my custom ribbon button two functions: first standard function from system "save" button, and seconds as above? Is it possible to run both on click?

Comment: I just noticed, that `SDK.REST.SetStateRequest` after success run `location.reload();`. Like: `SDK.REST.SetStateRequest(entity, ....getId(), 0, statuscode, location.reload(), genericErrorCallback);`. May it be the case?